# trying to run npm install epexcharts react-apexcharts command

Tags: npm

I'm trying to run a npm install epexcharts react-apexcharts command, and get an error that looks like this :

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/epexcharts - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'epexcharts@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-15T00_48_54_690Z-debug-0.log

I tried to reinstall npm, but seems like the issue remains the same

Answer (score 1):

The error you have is basically telling you that the package which you are looking for does not exist in the npm registry and you can check that yourself here: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=epexcharts

Or you can simply run the npm command to check if this library exists or not before installing it: `npm search epexcharts`.

But I think you are writing actually the false command which instead you should write: `npm install react-apexcharts`.